# Unit test ignore and provide explanation about it

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Is it possible to provide an explicative message in the Ignore decorator to a unit test in C#, like this?

```
[TestMethod]
[Ignore("This is intended to work locally only because lack of permissions")]
public void TestStartAcquireIfEmpty()
{

}
```

So that in case a future development is done, this decorator can be removed from the unit test

Comment: MsTest has [it](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/blob/ec18af6f90c272f68f48d9d0b94c71b8e276c7a0/src/TestFramework/MSTest.Core/Attributes/VSTestAttributes.cs#L150) and NUnit [too](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/ad49f27294bd0f2677d8699756c6ccb10df600f8/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Attributes/IgnoreAttribute.cs#L48).

Comment: ^^ `[Fact(Skip="reason")]` in [xUnit](https://xunit.net/docs/comparisons)

Comment: looking for a solution in MsTest

Comment: @GuruStron I was unaware of it, please answer my question and I will grant it as valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three of the most popular .NET test frameworks allow to mark test as ignored and provide ignore reason:

- MsTest's `IgnoreAttribute` has [constructor](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/blob/ec18af6f90c272f68f48d9d0b94c71b8e276c7a0/src/TestFramework/MSTest.Core/Attributes/VSTestAttributes.cs#L150) accepting `message` parameter
- Similarly NUnit's `IgnoreAttribute` has [constructor](https://github.com/microsoft/testfx/blob/ec18af6f90c272f68f48d9d0b94c71b8e276c7a0/src/TestFramework/MSTest.Core/Attributes/VSTestAttributes.cs#L150) accepting `reason` parameter
- XUnit requires to fill [`Skip`](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/3aeb38c4eeb0cc8053119fdd638da943afa0d5a9/src/xunit.v3.core/FactAttribute.cs) property (which is of string type) to ignore test

Answer (score 2):

You could add this line as the first line of your test:

```
Assert.Inconclusive("This is intended to work locally only because lack of permissions");
```

The test result will be shown as inconclusive with this message.